# Recursive shared mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I've been looking for an implementation of a `recursive shared mutex` to handle a very special data tree inside a heavy multi-threaded application.

Because boost and the stdlib does not have this special type, I wrote one myself. However, I am not sure if I missed something...

You find the full implementation with tests at [github](https://github.com/Viatorus/recursive_shared_mutex). Tested with GCC 5.4.

**Features**

- Recursive for exclusive ownership with lock and lock_shared.
- Recursive for sharable ownership with lock_shared.
- Threads trying to get exclusive ownership have a higher priority then new threads trying to get sharable ownership.
- Maximum waiting writers, level of ownerships: uint32::max

**recursive_shared_mutex.hpp**

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2017 Toni Neubert, all rights reserved.
 */
#pragma once

#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>

class RecursiveSharedMutex {
public:
    /**
     * @brief Constructs the mutex.
     */
    RecursiveSharedMutex();

    /**
     * @brief Locks the mutex for exclusive write access for this thread.
     *              Blocks execution as long as write access is not available:
     *              * other thread has write access
     *              * other threads try to get write access
     *              * other threads have read access
     *
     *              A thread may call lock repeatedly.
     *              Ownership will only be released after the thread makes a matching number of calls to unlock.
     */
    void lock();

    /**
     * @brief Locks the mutex for sharable read access.
     *              Blocks execution as long as read access is not available:
     *              * other thread has write access
     *              * other threads try to get write access
     *
     *              A thread may call lock repeatedly.
     *              Ownership will only be released after the thread makes a matching number of calls to unlock_shared.
     */
    void lock_shared();

    /**
     * @brief Unlocks the mutex for this thread if its level of ownership is 1. Otherwise reduces the level of ownership
     *              by 1.
     */
    void unlock();

    /**
     * @brief Unlocks the mutex for this thread if its level of ownership is 1. Otherwise reduces the level of ownership
     *              by 1.
     */
    void unlock_shared();

private:
    /// Protects data access of mutex.
    std::mutex _mtx;
    /// Number of threads waiting for exclusive write access.
    std::atomic<uint32_t> _waitingWriters;
    /// Thread id of writer.
    std::atomic<std::thread::id> _writerThreadId;
    /// Level of ownership of writer thread.
    uint32_t _writersOwnership;
    /// Level of ownership of reader threads.
    std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, uint32_t> _readersOwnership;
};
```

**recursive_shared_mutex.cpp**

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2017 Toni Neubert, all rights reserved.
 */
#include "recursive_shared_mutex.hpp"
#include <cassert>

RecursiveSharedMutex::RecursiveSharedMutex() :
    _waitingWriters(0),
    _writersOwnership(1) {
}

void RecursiveSharedMutex::lock() {
    // Case 1:
    // * Thread has no ownership.
    // * Zero readers, no writer.
    // -> The thread gets exclusive ownership as writer.

    // Case 2:
    // * Thread has no ownership.
    // * Many readers, no writer.
    // -> Gets exclusive ownership as writer and waits until last reader is unlocked.

    // Case 3:
    // * Thread has no ownership.
    // * Zero readers, one writer.
    // -> Gets exclusive ownership as writer after other writer thread is unlocked.

    // Case 4:
    // * Thread has no ownership.
    // * Zero readers, one writer.
    // * Many threads try to get exclusive ownership.
    // -> Various attempts until exclusive ownership as writer has been acquired. The acquisition order is arbitrarily.

    // Case 5:
    // * Thread has exclusive ownership.
    // * Zero readers, one writer.
    // -> Increases threads level of ownership.

    // Case 6:
    // * Thread has sharable ownership.
    // -> Deadlock.

    auto threadId = std::this_thread::get_id();
    {
        // Increase level of ownership if thread has already exclusive ownership.
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);
        if (_writerThreadId == threadId) {
            ++_writersOwnership;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Notify the new waiting writer.
    assert(_waitingWriters != 0x7fffffff);
    _waitingWriters += 1;

    for (;;) {
        // Attempt to get exclusive ownership.
        std::thread::id emptyThreadId;
        if (_writerThreadId.compare_exchange_weak(emptyThreadId, threadId)) {
            for (;;) {
                // Wait until no readers exist.
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);
                if (_readersOwnership.size() == 0) {
                    // Notify a waiting writer is gone.
                    --_waitingWriters;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void RecursiveSharedMutex::lock_shared() {
    // Case 1:
    // * Thread has/has no ownership.
    // * Zero/Many readers, no writer.
    // -> The thread gets shared ownership as reader.

    // Case 2:
    // * Thread has no ownership.
    // * Zero readers, one writer.
    // -> Waits until writer thread unlocked. The thread gets shared ownership as reader.

    // Case 3:
    // * Thread has sharable ownership.
    // * Many readers, no writer.
    // -> Increases threads level of ownership.

    // Case 4:
    // * Thread has exclusive ownership.
    // * Zero readers, one writer.
    // -> Increases threads level of ownership.

    // Case 5:
    // * Thread has no ownership.
    // * Zero/Many readers, one/no writer.
    // * Many threads try to get exclusive ownership.
    // -> Waits until all exclusive ownership requests are handled. The thread gets shared ownership as reader.

    auto threadId = std::this_thread::get_id();
    {
        // Increase level of ownership if thread has already exclusive ownership.
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);

        // As writer.
        if (_writerThreadId == threadId) {
            ++_writersOwnership;
            return;
        }

        // As reader.
        if (_readersOwnership.count(threadId) != 0) {
            ++_readersOwnership[threadId];
            return;
        }
    }

    for (;;) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);

        // Wait until no writer is waiting or writing.
        if (_waitingWriters.load() != 0 || _writerThreadId != std::thread::id()) {
            continue;
        }

        // Add new reader ownership.
        _readersOwnership.insert(std::make_pair(threadId, 1));
        return;
    }
}

void RecursiveSharedMutex::unlock() {
    // Case 1:
    // * Thread has exclusive ownership.
    // -> If threads level of ownership is 0, releases exclusive ownership otherwise decrements threads level of
    //      ownership.

    // Case 2:
    // * Thread has no/has sharable ownership.
    // -> In debug mode: Assert will terminate program.
    // -> In release mode: Undefined behaviour! Case 1 will occur.

    assert(std::this_thread::get_id() == _writerThreadId);

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);
    {
        // Decrease writer threads level of ownership if not 1.
        if (_writersOwnership != 1) {
            --_writersOwnership;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Reset threads ownership.
    _writerThreadId = std::thread::id();
}

void RecursiveSharedMutex::unlock_shared() {
    // Case 1:
    // * Thread has sharable ownership.
    // -> If reader threads level of ownership is 0, releases sharable ownership otherwise decrements reader threads
    //    level of ownership.

    // Case 2:
    // * Thread has exclusive ownership.
    // -> Decrements threads level of ownership.

    // Case 3:
    // * Thread has no ownership.
    // -> In debug mode: Assert will terminate program.
    // -> In release mode: Undefined behaviour!

    // Reduce readers recursive depth.
    // Remove reader from map if depth == 0.
    auto threadId = std::this_thread::get_id();

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);

    // Decrease writer threads level of ownership if not 1.
    if (_writerThreadId == threadId) {
        --_writersOwnership;
        return;
    }

    assert(_readersOwnership.count(threadId) == 1);

    // Decrease threads level of ownership if not 1.
    if (_readersOwnership[threadId] != 1) {
        --_readersOwnership[threadId];
        return;
    }

    // Remove readers ownership.
    _readersOwnership.erase(threadId);
}
```

Comment: I recommend having a look at [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95993/recursive-shared-mutex-implementation) as well.

Comment: The github link is out of date. Can you update it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the repo doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I had asked about the repo to see if you had a separate license there or if you wanted this to fall under CodeReview's Creative Commons license.

Comment: CRs Creative Commons Licence.

Answer (score 2):

One thought I had on this: wouldn't it play nicer if there was a thread yield outside the mutex in the tight for-loops? Or perhaps we scale up to that?

I've also been using this `try_lock` addition;

```
bool RecursiveSharedMutex::try_lock() {
    auto threadId = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::thread::id emptyThreadId;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);

    if (_writerThreadId == threadId) {
        ++_writersOwnership;
        return true;
    }

    if (_readersOwnership.size() == 0 && _writerThreadId.compare_exchange_weak(emptyThreadId, threadId))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```